# Shape error while converting Image to JSON file

Tags: python, json, numpy, rest, mlflow

I am trying to convert image to JSON file and POST it with REST API by using MLFLow. Below you can see my code. I got an error like "cannot reshape array of size 535500 into shape (1,4096)". Can you please help me. Thank you in advance.

```
import json
import cv2
import requests
import base64
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


data = np.asarray(Image.open('Dataset/test2/dog_PNG50348.png').convert('LA'))
data = data.reshape((1, 64*64))
columns = [f"col_{c}" for c in range(0, data[0].shape[0])]
dct = {"columns": columns, "data": [data[0].tolist()]}
print(json.dumps(dct, indent=2) + "\n")

#print(data)
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
request_uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/invocations'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        response = requests.post(request_uri, data=json.dumps(dct,indent=2)+"\n", headers=headers)
        print(response.content)
        print('done!!!')
    except Exception as ex:
        raise (ex)
```

Comment: Have you checked the shape of the image before reshaping it to see whether the size matches?

Comment: Yes, but this time I am getting bad request error